# Identify Quad Flat package

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, qfn

[image]I looked for days trying to find datasheet to this component. I concluded that this is a Quad Flat No-lead. But trying to search the marking code gets me nowhere. I did however find couple websites selling it, but it looked to me it's a scam. Pay now and never see your product. No contact information.

Also, I found some datasheet for an QFN32, but comparing what the pins do is different. And that's where I am stuck.

This chip is from a gps that won't turn on. I believe that it's making a noise and that might be the problem.

I am asking if someone know anything about this chip and what would be the equivalent replacement some that I can study its data to farther trouble shoot it.
I appreciate any comments and answers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Component ID questions are *not off topic*, they are if they have a bad picture however. The OP took time to post good pictures, leave the question open

Comment: @laptop2d, some members are like this. If they don't know the answer they vote it down just because they have the privilege. They don't even give reasons.

Comment: I cannot identify the circuit, however an idea came to mind: For consumer products, produced in large volumes, there is always a risk the circuit is an proprietary ASIC not intended for resale as separate spare part. That would explain why you cannot find any datasheet or specification for it.